# Style the html audio tag from default settings

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, shadow-dom

I am trying to style the audio tag so that it appears the same in Firefox and IE as it already does in Chrome.

I have found a website with some tags that use the shadow DOM to change it but it only provides tags to change the Chrome one?

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/aefd6e25064c08e0cc9a

Comment: Can you show us your code please

Comment: if you show your code then we will be able to understand your issue.

Comment: you have to create your own interface with an hidden audio tag that you can controle via Javascript commands

Comment: I don't think you can style the default styling - if , then you'd probably have to access each browser (on each platform) separately. But I have used `jplayer` which uses native html5 audio (and video) and which allows you to style their player as you like: http://jplayer.org/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response I thought stackoverflow was going to email me if anyone replied!  thanks Johannes that worked great